# How can I change the behavior of a Snap application depending on the environment (Production vs. Development)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

The default behavior for an uncaught runtime exception in Snap is to display a white page containing the error.  This is great for development mode, but really terrible for production.

I have my application setup to catch the exception and log the error so that displays something more attractive to the user when something bad happens.  How can I change it so that this only happens when I am in production mode?

```
app :: SnapletInit App App
app = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
    h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
    s <- nestSnaplet "sess" sess $
                 initCookieSessionManager "site_key.txt" "sess" (Just 86400)

    d <- nestSnaplet "db" db pgsInit

    addRoutes routes

    wrapSite (<|> notFound)
    -- TODO: figure out how make this only catch errors when in production mode
    wrapSite internalServerError

    initFlashNotice h sess
    addConfig h $ mempty & scInterpretedSplices .~ userSessionSplices sess
    return $ App h s d

internalServerError :: AppHandler () -> AppHandler ()
internalServerError h =
    catch h (\ (e :: SomeException) -> do
        logError $ B.pack $ show e
        modifyResponse (setResponseCode 500)
        render "errors/500")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap provides the [getEnvironment](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.14.0.5/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:getEnvironment) function for this purpose.  This function gets the environment passed to [runSnaplet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.14.0.5/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:runSnaplet).  The environment defaults to "devel" but can be changed at runtime with the -e command line option.  If you run your application like this:

```
dist/build/myapp/myapp -e prod
```

Then `getEnvironment` will return "prod".  You can use that like this:

```
notFound = do
  e <- getEnvironment
  case e of
    "devel" -> develErrorPage
    _       -> productionErrorPage
```

Comment: I have no reason to display naked exceptions when the application is compiled without the `-f development` flag, so what I'm looking for is an answer that checks *that* flag, not the one passed in when running the application.

Comment: That function just gets the environment string set by the user.  What you do with it is up to you.  Why not just display your nice looking exception page all the time?  If you need more detailed information for debugging purposes, you can write it to stdout or a log file.

Comment: Logging the error would require tailing the log the entire time I am doing development.  That's rather inconvenient since I have to refresh my browser to get it to recompile.  Displaying it in the browser is the most efficient way to obtain the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **DEVELOPMENT** flag passed to the preprocessor when compiling for development mode.

```
#ifndef DEVELOPMENT
wrapSite internalServerError
#endif
```

This is ugly and I was really hoping there was something better since it only works by recompiling.

Comment: @cimmanon rewrote my answer using the preprocessor directive.  Regrettably it requires recompiling.

Comment: Hm, yes, I tried experimenting with that last night, but doing a `cabal clean` + `cabal install` (production) or `cabal install -f development` (development) both produce the same results:  the internalServerError handler always runs when I create an exception.